# TLS 1.2 запрос на node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, tls

У меня два  одинаковых запроса возвращают разные результаты. Необходимо сделать запрос на node.js (tls 1.2), подскажите пожалуйста как сгенерировать клиентский ключ или сертификат, можете описать процедуру с нуля. Вот пример с документации.

```js
var fs = require('fs')
    , path = require('path')
    , certFile = path.resolve(__dirname, 'ssl/client.crt')
    , keyFile = path.resolve(__dirname, 'ssl/client.key')
    , caFile = path.resolve(__dirname, 'ssl/ca.cert.pem')
    , request = require('request');

var options = {
    url: 'https://api.some-server.com/',
    cert: fs.readFileSync(certFile),
    key: fs.readFileSync(keyFile),
    passphrase: 'password',
    ca: fs.readFileSync(caFile)
    }
};

request.get(options);
```

Comment: Из вопроса не ясно чего добивается автор. Сделать сервер с SSL, или сделать запрос по https.

Comment: @ФедорРусак, какой еще сервер. В вопросе десят раз написано - ЗАПРОС ЗАПРОС, ну и в примере как видно request.get. ?

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение. но сертификаты для запроса регистрировать не нужно, потому что это для пресловутого сервера нужно. в вашем примере явно используется ненативный модуль request. И похоже не по инструкции. поискать пример и перевести?

Comment: @ФедорРусак, а что такое тогда Certificate Signing Request

Comment: Согласно википедии это запрос к компании предоставившей сертификат для подтверждения подлинности. Это уже должно быть реализовано.

Comment: @ФедорРусак CERT_UNTRUSTED как избавиться от ошибки?

Comment: перед запросом добавь строку process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";